# How to understand "was ever to make"

Tags: meaning

The following is from the *Godfather*:

> The Don was a real man at the age of twelve. Short, dark slender,
>   living in the strange Moorish-looking village of Corleone in Sicily,
>   he had been born Vito Adolini, but when strange men came to kill the
>   son of the man they had murdered, his mother sent the young boy to
>   America to stay with friends. And in the new land hi changed his name
>   to Corleone to preserve some tie with his native village. It was one
>   of the few gestures of sentiments *he was ever to make*.

How to understand the last phrase I emphasized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's consider the part in question:

> *It was one of the few gestures of sentiments **he was ever to make**.*

To understand this, you should look at it as a combination of two common patterns: *be to do something* and *ever*.

- *[be to do something](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/be-to-do-something)* can be "used about someone or something in the past to say what would happen at a later time"
- *[ever](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/ever_1)* means "at any time"

Combine the two (*he was to make* and *ever*) together, and we get this meaning:

> In his life (from this point in this story), he made only *a few gestures of sentiments*, and this was one of them (*ever*).